# How Can I Follow Other facebook Accounts using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried follow and og.follow 
both didn't worked for me

if Anyone has the PHP Code Then Please Share{PHP SDK}

and Also How To Grab No Of Followers using Graph API{PHP SDK}

P.S:I Am Using BlackBerry Token

Answer (score 0):

The `/{user_id}/subscribers` edge is no longer available since v2.0:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> `/me/subscribers` and `/me/subscribedto` have been removed.